# Redirect old or expired urls to 404 page with ststus code 404, using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, redirect

We have a site in core php. We some links that are not in use now. So we want to redirect visitor to 404 page with status code 404, without deleting that links form server.
Thanks

Comment: You can use: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you do *nothing* explicitly, and a link **no longer exists**, the system will take care of generating a 404.

If the link actually **still exists**, but you don't want visitors using it, you could redirect to a fake page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/dead_uri_1/blah  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/dead_uri_2/blecch  [NC]
RewriteRule  .  /link_out_of_service.php  [R=404,L]
```

and `/link_out_of_service.php` would just say "Sorry, this link you followed is no longer in service." I think you can give a 404 code in that manner, but you should check it on your server to make sure it works. You might even be able to add the original %{REQUEST_URI} as a Query String to have it displayed in a message on the page.

Note that this isn't quite a proper use of 404, but if you intend to never activate those URIs again, you could probably get away with it.